# Solr File Indexing map content by pages

Tags: apache, pdf, solr, multivalue

I would like to index files in Solr.
I have already made an "output script" with PHP, but my project leader has given me the task of displaying the page number of the found text.

So:
 - I am searching for the Word "Foo".
 - Solr returns the results and also the highlighted text.
 - Now I would like to know on which page this highlighted text is, to find it.

The files are *.pdf files.

One solution I have thought of would be to import the Text of the PDF Files in different fields? Or maybe in this one multivalued field named "content".

Maybe like this:

```
Json:
    content:
        1: "page one text",
        2: "page two text"
```

and so on?

Is this possible? Or is there a better way to find this information out? Thanks for your help! :-)

Comment: Hi Cyruxx - Welcome to StackOverflow. You might like to post the php code you have got already, that could help people suggest where to put changes etc!!

Comment: Hello Neil, this is only a Solr thing, not PHP :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a separate Solr document for every page of every PDF file. If you want to return only one result per file, then you can use [FieldCollapsing](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing) to group all the results from the same PDF file.

Comment: Hello, but I'm using the ExtractorHandler for this, so how is this possible? By the way, thanks for your solution. :)